# Hibernate tries to persist an existing entity which is detached

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data

I am struggling with this one. I have a couple of entities that look like this

```
@Entity
@Table
class UserEntity (
  @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity
@Table
class TokenEntity (
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @MapsId var user: UserEntity,
  @Id var id: Long? = null
)
```

I am experimenting with hexagonal architecture so I retrieve an `UserEntity` and transform it to a `User` domain object in the `UsersPersistenceAdapter`, then I create a `Token` domain object and transform it to a `TokenEntity` and save the entity in the `TokensPersistenceAdapter`

The domain objects look like this

```
class User(
  var email: String,
  var password: String,
  var id: UserId? = null
) {
  class UserId(var value: Long)
}

class Token(
  var value: String,
  var user: User,
  var id: TokenId? = null
) {
  class TokenId(var value: Long)
}
```

When I save the `TokenEntity` object I get the exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: es.test.backend.users.adapters.secondary.persistence.UserEntity`

Looking at the logs I see that hibernate is trying to persist the `UserEntity`

```
2019-12-11 00:00:59.270 DEBUG 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 8, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator
2019-12-11 00:00:59.270 TRACE 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Saving [es.test.backend.users.adapters.secondary.persistence.TokenEntity#8]
2019-12-11 00:00:59.270 TRACE 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST for: es.test.backend.users.adapters.secondary.persistence.TokenEntity
2019-12-11 00:00:59.270 TRACE 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist: es.test.backend.users.adapters.secondary.persistence.UserEntity
2019-12-11 00:00:59.740 TRACE 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.engine.spi.IdentifierValue   : ID unsaved-value: null
2019-12-11 00:00:59.740 TRACE 9813 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Detached instance of: es.test.backend.users.adapters.secondary.persistence.UserEntity
```

I am doing something pretty similar in a `@ManyToOne` relationship (the stuff about converting everything back and forth from an entity to a domain object) without any problems.

Here is a complete example

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {
    @Bean
    fun init(userRepository: UserRepository, tokenRepository: TokenRepository) = CommandLineRunner {
        val newUser = userRepository.save(User())
        val userDto = UserDto(newUser.id)
        val token = Token (user = User(userDto.id))
        tokenRepository.save(token)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@Entity
class UserEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null
)

class UserDto(val id: Long?)

// Fails
@Entity
class TokenEntity(
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @MapsId var user: UserEntity,
    @Id var id: Long? = null
)

// Works
//@Entity
//class TokenEntity(
//        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) var user: UserEntity,
//        @GeneratedValue @Id var id: Long? = null
//)

interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long>
interface TokenRepository : CrudRepository<TokenEntity, Long>
```

Can anybody see what is going on? I am creating a simple project in [GitHub](https://github.com/Quaiks/example-stackvoerflow) for illustrating the issue.

Comment: Seems to me that you haven't persisted `UserEntity` before persisting `TokenEntity`. If you are creating a new `UserEntity` from domain object `User`, the `UserEntity` object is in **detached** state.

Comment: The `UserEntity` is retrieved from the database but is converted to a `User` domain object and then converted again to a `UserEntit` with the same data.

Comment: I still think that you need to call `merge` or `findById` when adding `User` entity to `Token` entity, if you're using `Token(user = User(userDto.id))`, because you're trying to save an unmanaged/detached object (object that's not in the persistence context) when saving `Token` object. I also find it odd that the `@ManyToOne` type of relationship is working just fine (maybe you're not using it the same way). In both cases `User` is the parent in the relationship and needs to be saved before child (`Token`), because `Token` depends on `User`'s PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could store the `TokenEntity` was getting rid of the `@MapsId` and using a generated value

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tokens")
class TokenEntity(
    var value: String,
    @OneToOne var user: UserEntity,
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating the token entity with the id populated will cause the issue. If you are creating and saving a new token the id on the entity passed to save must be unvalued.